# Single-word -Someone can't fully explain or express their feelings

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word or a couple single words that would describe the situation of not being able to fully express/explain your feelings or emotions to someone so that you can get them to understand your situation or point of view? This doesn't quite include feelings.

Comment: Not able because you are excited? Or sad? Or confused?  Or any of the above?

Comment: that is exactly how I feel trying to answer your question. How about all of the above?

Comment: do you understand what I mean? do you ever feel that?

Comment: Do you mean that "you were too overcome with emotion to speak" ?

Comment: @Graffito no apparently not, according to his response to my answer.

Comment: it's a she actually

Comment: yeah...no emotions involved it's actually the absence  of emotions that makes it hard to explain

Comment: I understand this is a good enough and complicated answer to get exactly correct with the right words. That's what makes a good question so I needed to ask just in case someone else knew anything better

Comment: If you refer to "personal communication problem", I think that a one/two word(s) expression describing such situation will be difficult to find.

Comment: I guess...what did you have in mind?

Comment: Perhaps "expressive inhibition".

Comment: Thanks so much you guys...it seems as if this question would be something that would also become a question for most of you since you couldn't answer as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm having trouble **articulating** my true feelings.

Comment: That actually helps a lot more Thanks any more?

Comment: "Articulate" to me is the most accurate way of saying that but it's not very common. You would need to define it, which defeats the purpose. **hard to express** is about as long but much more understandable.

Answer (score 2):

This common, general phrase for any emotion might help you out:

> **be beside oneself** - be consumed by an emotion; experience an intense feeling

"I am besides myself right now. I have no words."

And there are these common words:

**Speechless**

**dumbfounded**

**dumbstruck**

**tongue-tied**

Comment: Thanks but that was not what I was looking for. I would like a single word

Comment: I provided 4 single words.

Comment: I understand..but what i am looking for doesn't really  involve emotions at all until afterwards

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. All of the singe words I provided do not involve emotional lack of speech.

Comment: There is a slight emotion behind it...anyways it's not exactly what I was looking for..can we look for something else?

Comment: Tongue-tied has emotion behind it? Speechless has emotion behind it? Can you explain better what you are looking for?

Comment: that's the problem I can't ...I'm looking for a word for that

Comment: Try to imagine what it feels like to be in my situation right now trying to explain...maybe you'll get a better understanding

Answer (score 2):

**Speechless**:

> unable to speak because of anger, surprise, etc. ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/speechless))

As this definition indicates, the cause of the condition is variable: it could be due to a sudden shock, excitement, sadness, anger, or a number of other things.

Taken literally it means a complete inability to express oneself, but in common usage a more figurative meaning is implied:

> I never expected to win this award.  I'm speechless.  I just can't believe it.  I'd like to thank my family, friends...

In this imaginary but very common "award acceptance speech," the speaker is obviously not "speechless," since he or she is speaking.  But the speaker uses the word to communicate how difficult it is to communicate the depth of his or her feelings in that moment.

Comment: I'm not sure that fits, it doesn't make me feel surprised,etc. It's not really one you can name with an emotion. Anything else?

Comment: There are many other ways the word can be used: in response to receiving an amazing gift or show of support, out of anger, out of frustration or confusion, etc.  If you want to give us the situation in which you experienced this, that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *I'm at a loss for words.*

Comment: somewhat but I would like a single word Thanks

Comment: The phrase *at a loss* is also used to convey the same intent. It's still not one word, but closer.

Comment: closer...kind of that might work